# Access Meta-Annotation inside Class (TypeScript)

Tags: typescript, angular

When I annotate a class with metadata in TypeScript, e.g. to create an Angular2 component, can I access the metadata inside that class?

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    templateUrl: '/app/components/app/app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {

    // can I access 'templateUrl' from above annotation here?

}
```

Comment: The general answer is "it depends", a decorator is just something that wraps your class. It is possible for it to expose a proprerty or not - as it chooses. It doesn't _have_ to let you have access to it - in fact it may choose to ignore the parameter passed to it altogether.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[@PierreDuc's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34466523/317951) doesn't work for me in *Angular 5*. I did some further reading (sorry, I can't find all the relevant links to share), and came up with the following:

```typescript
let decorator: Type<any>;
// you can cast the component class
decorator = (<any>AppComponent).__annotations__[0];
// or use with lodash.get
decorator = get(AppComponent, '__annotations__[0]');

//
// obviously, this is an array, and based on your app,
// you may have multiple decorators on one class, so iterate them
//


// if you want to just grab some data from the @Component:
const templateUrl: string = decorator.templateUrl;
// or from a @NgModule:
const declarations: Type<any>[] = decorator.declarations;


// or if you're trying to decide whether this is in fact a component:
if (decorator instanceof Component) {
  // do things
}
// or a provider
if (decorator instanceof Injectable) {
  // do different things
}
// or a module:
if (decorator instanceof NgModule) {
  // do things
}

// etc...
```

I have not yet upgraded my app to Angular 6, so I have not verified that this has not changed.

Related:

- Here's any interesting article about *creating* a custom decorator: https://blog.angularindepth.com/implementing-custom-component-decorator-in-angular-4d037d5a3f0d

Comment: Nice answer! This is indeed how it should be done now, although if you don't care about IE, you can use the native [Reflect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect) now. `Reflect.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(AppComponent, '__annotations__');`

Comment: This answer is more current, making it the accepted answer. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46937746/how-to-retrieve-a-components-metadata-in-angular for a bit more details

Answer (score 20):

With the new angular version, you should use the native [`Reflect`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect) object. No IE11 support though:

```
const annotations = Reflect.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(MyModule, '__annotations__').value;
```

Read Jeff Fairley's answer below on what to do with the data after that

<strike>You can see an annotation/decorator as a normal function call. To this function the 'Class/Function' object (not instance) gets send in the first parameter, and the parameters (metadata) in the second argument.</strike>

However it depends on the implementation of that function if something gets added for instance to the prototype of the class (bad practice/exposing property). The TypeScript compiler and Angular2 do things differently though.

They use the `__decorate` and `__metadata` functions, which are generated by the TypeScript compiler. The data gets added with the [Object.defineProperty()](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) function. The package responsible for this is [Reflect](https://github.com/rbuckton/ReflectDecorators). (which under the hood uses the `Object.defineProperty()` function in combination with a `WeakMap`).

The function `Reflect.defineMetadata()` is used to set the annotations, and to obtain them the obvious `Reflect.getMetadata()`.

TLDR;

- To get the annotations from a class/component in angular2, you have
  to use:

  ```
  Reflect.getMetadata('annotations', ComponentClass); //@Component({}), @Pipe({}), ...
  ```
- To get the annotations from the constructor paramaters in angular2, you have to use:

  ```
  Reflect.getMetadata('parameters', ComponentClass); //@Inject()
  ```
- To get the annotations from a property in a class in angular2, you
  have to use:

  ```
  Reflect.getMetadata('propMetadata', ComponentClass); //@HostBinding(), @Input(), ...
  ```

Answer (score 6):

We were using this solution and found out that AOT strips out `__annotations__` (which is also the default for `--prod` builds,) making it a no-go for us.

Fortunately if you're dealing with components, there's an alternative that works in both and doesn't use strings:

```
const components = [ MyComponent ];
/*
  ...
  Anything that can be injected into
*/
constructor(private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) {
  // For each component
  components.forEach(element => {
    // Get its resolved factory
    const factory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(element);

    console.log('Factory:', factory);
    console.log('Selector:', factory.selector);
  });
}
```

Since it's dealing with proper types and interfaces, it's also linter-approved!

Comment: Should be noted that of the out of all possible [annotations](https://angular.io/api/core/Component) only `inputs`, `outputs`, `queries` and `selector` are accessible from the `ComponentFactory`.

Comment: This doesn't work with directives unfortunately: `Type passed in is not ComponentType, it does not have 'ɵcmp' property.`

Answer (score 0):

as John Neuhaus stated, angular just remove **annotations** property when aot compiling. So, we can just do `ng serve --aot=false`, and now you may find **annotations** show up when you do `console.dir(AppComponent);`