# How can I get metadata for the current module in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, metadata, angular2-aot, angular2-modules

I want to get the metadata for the current **NgModule** in order to get the list of `declarations` and `providers` in order to fill in a dynamic module I create to display components in a modal.

How can that be done?

Answer (score 1):

You can access the declarations using the [**`reflect-metadata`**](https://github.com/rbuckton/reflect-metadata) package. You do however need to install this package and include it in your project. After that you can get the annotations like this:

```
let annotations: DecoratorFactory[] = Reflect.getMetadata('annotations', ModuleClass);
```

If the `@NgModule` is the only annotation on there, which I would guess it is, you can access the declarations like this, otherwise you have to guess the right `index`:

```
let declarations: any[] = annotations[0].declarations;
```

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34466523/3106920) for further reference

Comment: And what if I want to get the current module without knowing which one is it?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no such thing as a current module. Because your application can consist of multiple `NgModules` at once. What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: If you can give plnkr.co implementation that will be great