# Typescript and Angular: Type a string to a component class

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

a function is passing the name of my component via a string but I need it to be the actual component class:

Current: "MyComponent"
Need: MyComponent

I need to "convert" it so It's passing correctly. I have an `ngFor` that spits out values and I'm trying to use piping to convert it:

```
<div id="grid">
    <gridster [options]="options">
    <gridster-item [item]="item" *ngFor="let item of dashboard;let i = index;">
      <div class="grid-header drag-handle">
        <span class="handle-icon"><i class="material-icons">open_with</i></span>
        <span class="close-icon" (click)="removePanel(item)"><i class="material-icons">close</i></span>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-content">
        <ndc-dynamic [ndcDynamicComponent]="item.viewType | dynamicComponent"></ndc-dynamic>
      </div>
    </gridster-item>
  </gridster>
</div>
```

Above it's `item.viewType` that's a strong coming from my item array. I'm passing the value to a `dynamicComponent` custom pipe. I have my components imported into my `dynamic-component.pipe.ts`. I just need to change the string to the specified `viewType` and return the `typed` value:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
//pulling in all the possible components
import * from '../../views';

@Pipe({
  name: 'dynamicComponent'
})
export class DynamicComponentPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: string): any {


  }

}
```

Comment: maybe check https://stackoverflow.com/a/42951200/1987977

Comment: I get the rough just of what their doing (I'm new to angular2) but I don't fully grasp how to relate it to my `pipe`

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to manually create a mapping between string values and the components. Components are actually named functions which can be minimized to shorter variable names when compiling for production.

```
import ComponentA from '../views/ComponentA'; 
import ComponentB from '../views/ComponentA';

const componentMap = {
    'ComponentA': ComponentA,
    'ComponentB': ComponentB
};

@Pipe({name: 'dynamicComponent'})
export class DynamicComponentPipe implements PipeTransform {
   transform(value: string): any {
       if(componentMap[value]) {
          return componentMap[value];
       }
       throw new Error(`${componentMap} component was not found`);
   }
}
```

**UPDATED:**

The problem with using the name of a component at runtime is that it can be minimized into a smaller variable name for production. Therefore, doing something like `views['MyComponent']` won't work later when `MyComponent` is renamed to something like `a12`.

An alternative approach is to use the component's *selector* string value to select the component. Each component in Angular has to be a unique selector string. So this is a safe value to use as a key.

You can access (at least in Angular 5) the component's metadata via the `__annotations__` property. This property is an array that contains a the metadata.

So you could try something like:

```
import * as views from '../views';

@Pipe({name: 'dynamicComponent'})
export class DynamicComponentPipe implements PipeTransform {
   transform(value: string): any {
       const view = views.filter((component)=>component['__annotations__'][0]['selector'] === value));
       if(view) {
          return view;
       }
       throw new Error(`A component with selector "${value}" was not found`);
   }
}
```

Furthermore, you could drop the need for a `views` file by accessing the `ngModule` directly and iterating all components to find a matching selector. Modules will have the same `__annotations__` property.

Comment: I'm pulling in my list of possible components by placing them in a `ts` file using `export` for each then importing them into my `pipe` file with `import * as views from '../../views/views';` This returns an an array with key value pairs already. Couldn't I just keep using that?

Comment: FYI, I'm not saying you're wrong. Just asking if using `views` from the import above is acceptable since it's already an array and `views[value]` returns the same thing as what you did above.

Comment: I think the keys in `views` will be the minimized version in production. Just run `console.log(views)` from a production build to see if I'm right.

Comment: I see the concern. Listing out each component in the pipe file can be a bit heavy when others start working in this system. The `views.ts` file in the `views` directory is used to provide a single point of export. How would you suggest addressing that?

Comment: @dcp3450 how do you assign the string values to `item.viewType`? Do you have control over what those values can be?

Comment: @dcp3450 I updated my answer. I ran a quick test on my own angular project, and it seems to work for me.

Comment: I referenced this answer for my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46937746/how-to-retrieve-a-components-metadata-in-angular

Answer (score 0):

I did this pretty simple way:

I created a `views.ts` with all of my views exported at the root of my views directory. Then in directory that my pipe is being used I imported the `views` using:

`import * as views from '../../views/views'`

Then in my `transform` method I `return views[value];` where `value` is the string being pulled in from my template.

Comment: Won't this break in production when the JavaScript is minimized and function names are shorten.

Comment: i'm going to go with ¯\_(ツ)_/¯