# declarations meta data of an NgModule

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-decorators

Is it possible to at runtime query the `declarations` of a module class that is decorated with an `@NgModule`.

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
    ...
    ],
    declarations: [
        Component1,
        Component2,
        Component3
    ]
})
export class MyModule { }
```

So, what I am trying to accomplish is roughly:

```
const declarations: Type[] = MyModule.declarations;
```

Comment: Already answered here  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34465214/access-meta-annotation-inside-class-typescript/34466523#34466523

Comment: @AndrewReborn thanks for referencing my answer, but I'm afraid that's an old answer. Not sure if that still works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure, but I believe in AOT mode this answer will not work. Apart from that, this is a private/naughty access property and subject to change, but you can access the definition like this:

```
const descriptor = Reflect.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(MyModule, '__annotations__');

if (descriptor) {
  const decorator = descriptor.value && descriptor.value[0];

  if (decorator) {
    const { declarations } = decorator; 
  }
}
```